# Where can I find Blood Stone Chunks?

Tags: bloodborne

I've now got every weapon, all upgraded to the max Blood Stone Shard level, to the point where I'll soon max out on Blood Stone Shards in Storage.

I've upgraded the weapons I use fully with Twin Blood Stone Shards.

But I still haven't come across a single Blood Stone Chunk.

Where can I find some?

Comment: Just continue along the main path and you will come across quite a few of them. If I remember correctly, I found a lot in the Unseen Village and the following areas.

Comment: Yea the dead Snatchers in the Unseen Village all have a chunk or two.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got access to cainhurst castle, I think you can get 3 from there, can't remember where but you can just follow a guide for that. It is a high level area though so depending on your level you may find it tough. As well as the guaranteed chunks I mentioned, there are 2 enemy types here that can also drop the chunks if your lucky, the gargoyles and crawlers that you see outside the castle door.

Comment: The blue eyed werewolves in upper cathedral ward can also drop blood stone chunks

Comment: I have farmed cainhurst castle a lot and never had a gargoyle or crawly thing drop a chunk, they usually drop twin shards or gems. I wonder if insight effects what they drop. edit: there are a few lying around the ground though but many more in the unseen village.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't found any Blood Stone Chunks around the areas you are exploring, you likely just need to advance further into the game. The first one that you can find in the main story areas is in the Forbidden Forest with areas after that having progressively more and more available. Additionally, you can farm Blood Stone Chunks from

> the Skeletal Scourge Beasts in Yahar'gul, Unseen Village and the Scourge Beasts with blue eyes in the Upper Cathedral Ward. The blue eyed Scourge Beasts in the Upper Cathedral Ward are faster to get to, so they are generally your best bet for farming chunks.

If you go to farm Blood Stone Chunks, be sure to equip an Eye Caryll Rune if you have one available, since it will make it more likely for the mobs to drop items.